# Measure the distribution shift of categorical variables

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, python, model-evaluation, categorical-encoding

In the model performance monitoring stage, if you want to measure the change of a distribution of a numerical variable, `Population Stability Index` can be used. But what metrics can we use for categorical variables? For example, if I have a categorical variable like a country code, since it is not ordinal, so converting it to a number is not a reliable way.

Comment: For a purely categorical variable, the idea of a "shift" does not make sense. You can measure "overall change" in various ways, though, e.g. using metrics derived from the chi-square statistic.

Answer (score 1):

**If you are looking at the univariate shift**

If the feature is not encoded, the only thing that you can do is check if the category is in the training data. Then how it affects the specific model that you are using, behaviour will be different for a NN or for a Decision Tree based model.

If the feature is encoded, then you have to look of how your encoder handless unseen categories.

**If you are looking at the general shift**

I will expect that it affects also the rest of covariates. Then you need to have a wider look at the data.

Being very biased, I will suggest my own work:

- Explanation Shift: How did the distribution shift affect the model? https://arxiv.org/pdf/2303.08081.pdf
- Whose implementation you can check on the skshift python package https://skshift.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

In the related work section, you can find other approaches.
Would love some feedback to see if it works for your case